# Special characters issue in python

Tags: python, pyscripter

I have a problem about this code

```
def print_text(text):
 print text

#---------- excut cod -----------
print_text("Dêqên Tibetan")
#---------- end cod -------------
```

When I run from pyscripter, application only shows

```
D?q?n Tibetan
```

how do I fix it?

This is after press play >

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTC4m.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZzsh.png)

Answer (score 1):

just do

```
print u"Dêqên Tibetan"
```

in python 2 or

```
print(u"Dêqên Tibetan")
```

in python 3

Comment: I think you forgot the "u" character prefixing the quote.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the argument value there you put the unicode letter [u]:

```
print_text(u"Dêqên Tibetan")
```

Answer (score 0):

another way:

```
def print_text(text):
   print unicode(text, "utf-8") # you can use other encode

print_text("Dêqên Tibetan")
```

Comment: other encode "utf-16" say UnicodeDecodeError please fix

Comment: you are jinyus Javier Clavero I want to mery you

Comment: Forgive the link above was not correct, the error appears to be PyScripter Ide. Try on the command line or other IDE, i.e. Pycharm